# Error when creating an excutable .jar on a javafx program

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, executable-jar

So I'm currently using Eclipse to develop my program, it's already done and I need to make it an excecutable file. When I export my program with the export option it actually creates the jar, but when it is run, an error prompts, like it can't find JavaFx, the code works perfectly fine on Eclipse.

The .jar was created like this in Eclipse: export -> Runnable JAR file -> selected the already configured main -> finish

Tried using different options

with Extract required libraries into generated JAR the error is this one:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class interfaz.Run
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

And with Package required libraries into generated JAR is at it follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:545)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:83)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:453)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:447)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:446)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
javafx.application.Application
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 14 more
```

I'm not really sure what did I do wrong

This is the code, but again, it works fine on the IDE:

```
package interfaz;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import algoritmo.Hamming;
import algoritmo.NumConverter;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Run extends Application {
int timesLooped = 0;

Stage window;
Scene mainScene, ham1, ham2, bitChange, ham3;
String numToHam;
String parity;
int windX = 1360;
int windY = 720;

HBox tableNnums;
Text detection;
HBox secondT;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    NumConverter converter = new NumConverter();

    window = primaryStage;

    //First scene
    VBox canvasMain = new VBox(100);
    HBox hammingStory = new HBox(450);
    canvasMain.setPadding(new Insets(10, 50, 20, 50));
    canvasMain.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

    //Second scene
    VBox canvasHam1 = new VBox(174);
    canvasHam1.setPadding(new Insets(10, 50, 20, 50));
    canvasHam1.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

    //Third scene
    VBox canvasHam2 = new VBox(90);
    canvasHam2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 50, 20, 50));
    canvasHam2.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

    //Fourth scene
    VBox canvasBit = new VBox(175);
    canvasBit.setPadding(new Insets(10, 50, 20, 50));
    canvasBit.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

    //Fifth scene
    VBox canvasHam3 = new VBox(70);
    canvasHam3.setPadding(new Insets(10, 50, 20, 50));
    canvasHam3.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);


    //First scene layout
    Text mainHeader = new Text("Código Hamming");
    mainHeader.setFont(new Font(30));

    Image logo = new Image(new FileInputStream("./media/logo-tec.png"));
    ImageView TEClogo = new ImageView(logo);
    TEClogo.setFitHeight(355); 
    TEClogo.setFitWidth(400);
    TEClogo.setPreserveRatio(true);

    //Hamming image
    VBox hammingImage = new VBox(10);
    hammingImage.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    Label caption = new Label("Richard Wesley Hamming");
    Image hamming = new Image(new FileInputStream("./media/hamming.jpg"));
    ImageView hammingV = new ImageView(hamming);
    hammingV.setFitHeight(305); 
    hammingV.setFitWidth(170);
    hammingV.setPreserveRatio(true);
    hammingImage.getChildren().addAll(hammingV, caption);
    Text someStory = new Text("En informática, el código de Hamming es un código detector y corrector de errores\nque lleva el nombre de su inventor, Richard Hamming.\nEn los datos codificados en Hamming se pueden detectar errores\nen un bit y corregirlos, sin embargo no se distingue entre errores de dos bits\n y de un bit (para lo que se usa Hamming extendido). Esto representa\nuna mejora respecto a los códigos con bit de paridad, que pueden detectar\nerrores en sólo un bit, pero no pueden corregirlo.\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nDiseño Lógico Tarea 2 en Grupo\nIntegrantes:\n- Sebastian Rivera Soto 2016074041\n- Victor Bulgarelli 2016078592\n- Daniel Andrés Rojas 2016089821\n- Kevin Barquero Loria 2016038605");
    someStory.setFont(new Font(14));

    hammingStory.getChildren().addAll(someStory, hammingImage);

    canvasMain.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #bdbec1;");

    //Buttons
    Button go = new Button("Comenzar");
    go.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                fadeTransition(canvasMain, canvasHam1, ham1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    canvasMain.getChildren().addAll(mainHeader,TEClogo,hammingStory, go);

    mainScene = new Scene(canvasMain, windX, windY);

    //Second scene layout
    Text typeNChoose = new Text("Digite el número en hexadecimal al que le desea realizar el proceso\nademás seleccione el tipo de paridad deseado");
    typeNChoose.setFont(new Font(20));
    typeNChoose.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment:center");

    VBox form = new VBox(10);
    form.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    Text enterN = new Text("Digite número hexadecimal de 3 dígitos");
    TextField number = new TextField();
    number.setMaxWidth(70);
    form.getChildren().addAll(enterN, number);

    Text parityText = new Text("Tipo de paridad");
    RadioButton par = new RadioButton("Par");
    RadioButton odd = new RadioButton("Impar");

    ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

    par.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
    odd.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
    HBox radios = new HBox(2);
    radios.getChildren().addAll(par,odd);
    Group radiosG = new Group(radios);

    VBox parBut = new VBox(10);
    parBut.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    Button cal = new Button("Hamming");
    parBut.getChildren().addAll(parityText, radiosG);
    canvasHam1.getChildren().addAll(typeNChoose, form,parBut,cal);

    ham1 = new Scene(canvasHam1, windX, windY);

    //Third scene layout
    Text table1N = new Text("Tabla No.1\nCálculo de los bits de paridad en el código Hamming");
    table1N.setFont(new Font(18));

    HBox optB = new HBox(448);
    Button continuar = new Button("Cambiar un bit");
    Button continuarSin = new Button("Ir a segunda tabla");
    Button Volver = new Button("Volver a inicio");
    optB.getChildren().addAll(Volver,continuarSin, continuar);

    canvasHam2.getChildren().addAll(table1N);

    ham2 = new Scene(canvasHam2, windX,windY);

    //fourth scene layout
    Text bitChanger = new Text("Digite el número que representa la posición\ndel bit a cambiar");
    bitChanger.setFont(new Font(20));
    bitChanger.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment:center");

    Text originalArray = new Text();
    originalArray.setFont(new Font(15));

    VBox formToBit = new VBox(10);
    formToBit.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    Text instruction = new Text("Digite un número entre 1 y 17");
    instruction.setFont(new Font(15));
    TextField bitToChange = new TextField();
    bitToChange.setMaxWidth(34);
    formToBit.getChildren().addAll(instruction, bitToChange);

    Button changeNow = new Button("Cambiar bit y desplegar segunda tabla");

    canvasBit.getChildren().addAll(bitChanger,originalArray ,formToBit,changeNow);
    bitChange = new Scene(canvasBit, windX, windY);

    //fifth scene layout
    Text table2Text = new Text("Tabla No.2\nComprobación de los bits de paridad");
    table2Text.setFont(new Font(20));
    Text sol2 = new Text("No se encontraron errores");
    Button restart = new Button("Volver a inicio");

    canvasHam3.getChildren().add(table2Text);
    ham3 = new Scene(canvasHam3, windX, windY);

    cal.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(converter.covertFromHexToBin(number.getText()) == "Su número no es de tres dígitos" || converter.covertFromHexToBin(number.getText()) == "Error su número no es hexadecimal") {
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
                VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);
                dialogVbox.getChildren().add(new Text(converter.covertFromHexToBin(number.getText()) + "\nIngrese otra entrada"));
                dialogVbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
                Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 300, 70);
                dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
                dialog.show();
                number.setText("");
            }else if(toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle() == null){
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
                VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);
                dialogVbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
                dialogVbox.getChildren().add(new Text("Seleccione alguna opción de paridad"));
                Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 300, 70);
                dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
                dialog.show();
            }else {         

                //Checks if table existed
                if(timesLooped > 0) {
                    canvasHam2.getChildren().removeAll(tableNnums, optB);
                }

                numToHam = number.getText();
                RadioButton tick = (RadioButton)toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle();
                parity = tick.getText();

                tableNnums = new HBox(80);
                VBox conversions = new VBox(30);

                //Conversiones
                Text title = new Text("Analizado");
                Text hexadecimal = new Text();
                Text decimal = new Text();
                Text binary = new Text();
                Text bcdT = new Text();
                conversions.getChildren().addAll(title,hexadecimal, decimal, binary, bcdT);

                //Crea tabla
                GridPane hamT1 = new GridPane();

                hamT1.add(new Text("p1"), 1, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p2"), 2, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d1"), 3, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p3"), 4, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d2"), 5, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d3"), 6, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d4"), 7, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p4"), 8, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d5"), 9, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d6"), 10, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d7"), 11, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d8"), 12, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d9"), 13, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d10"), 14, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d11"), 15, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p5"), 16, 0);
                hamT1.add(new Text("d12"), 17, 0);

                hamT1.add(new Text("Palabra de datos(sin paridad):"), 0, 1);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p1"), 0, 2);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p2"), 0, 3);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p3"), 0, 4);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p4"), 0, 5);
                hamT1.add(new Text("p5"), 0, 6);
                hamT1.add(new Text("Palabra de datos(con paridad):"), 0, 7);

                hamT1.setHgap(30);
                hamT1.setVgap(45);

                tableNnums.getChildren().addAll(hamT1, conversions);

                hexadecimal.setText("Hexadecimal: "+ number.getText().toUpperCase());
                decimal.setText("Decimal: " + Integer.toString(converter.anyToDecimal(16, number.getText())));
                binary.setText("Binario: " + converter.covertFromHexToBin(number.getText()));
                bcdT.setText("BCD: " + converter.decimalToBCD(Integer.toString(converter.anyToDecimal(16, number.getText()))));
                matrix = new Hamming().hammingMatrix(converter.covertFromHexToBin(number.getText()), parity);

                for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.get(i).size(); j++) {
                        hamT1.add(new Text(matrix.get(i).get(j)), j+1, i+1);
                    }
                }

                canvasHam2.getChildren().addAll(tableNnums, optB);

                number.setText("");

                try {
                    fadeTransition(canvasHam1, canvasHam2, ham2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    restart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            timesLooped++;
            try {
                fadeTransition(canvasHam3, canvasMain, mainScene);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //Third scene buttons
    continuar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            originalArray.setText("El codigo original es:\n" + new Hamming().getCodedChain(matrix.get(matrix.size()-1)));

            try {
                fadeTransition(canvasHam2, canvasBit, bitChange);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    continuarSin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(timesLooped > 0) {
                canvasHam3.getChildren().removeAll(secondT,detection,sol2, restart);
            }

            Hamming solution = new Hamming();
            matrix2 = solution.verifyCode(new Hamming().getCodedChain(matrix.get(matrix.size()-1)), parity);

            GridPane hamT2 = new GridPane();

            hamT2.add(new Text("p1"), 1, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p2"), 2, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d1"), 3, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p3"), 4, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d2"), 5, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d3"), 6, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d4"), 7, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p4"), 8, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d5"), 9, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d6"), 10, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d7"), 11, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d8"), 12, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d9"), 13, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d10"), 14, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d11"), 15, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p5"), 16, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("d12"), 17, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("Prueba de paridad"), 18, 0);
            hamT2.add(new Text("Bit de paridad"), 19, 0);

            hamT2.add(new Text("Palabra de datos recibida:"), 0, 1);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p1"), 0, 2);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p2"), 0, 3);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p3"), 0, 4);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p4"), 0, 5);
            hamT2.add(new Text("p5"), 0, 6);

            hamT2.setHgap(30);
            hamT2.setVgap(45);

            for(int i = 0; i < matrix2.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < matrix2.get(i).size(); j++) {
                    hamT2.add(new Text(matrix2.get(i).get(j)), j+1, i+1);
                }
            }
            secondT = new HBox(10);
            secondT.getChildren().addAll(hamT2);

            canvasHam3.getChildren().addAll(secondT, sol2,restart);

            try {
                fadeTransition(canvasHam2, canvasHam3, ham3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Volver.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            timesLooped++;
            try {
                fadeTransition(canvasHam2, canvasMain, mainScene);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //Fourth scene button
    changeNow.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                if(Integer.parseInt(bitToChange.getText()) > 17 || Integer.parseInt(bitToChange.getText()) < 1) {
                    final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
                    VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);
                    dialogVbox.getChildren().add(new Text("El numero que ingresó\nno esta en el rango especificado" + "\nIngrese otra entrada"));
                    dialogVbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
                    Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 300, 100);
                    dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
                    dialog.show();
                    bitToChange.setText("");
                }else {
                    matrix.get(matrix.size()-1).set(Integer.parseInt(bitToChange.getText())-1, reverseBit(matrix.get(matrix.size()-1).get(Integer.parseInt(bitToChange.getText())-1)));

                    Hamming solution = new Hamming();
                    matrix2 = solution.verifyCode(new Hamming().getCodedChain(matrix.get(matrix.size()-1)), parity);

                    if(timesLooped > 0) {
                        canvasHam3.getChildren().removeAll(secondT,detection,sol2, restart);
                    }

                    GridPane hamT2 = new GridPane();

                    hamT2.add(new Text("p1"), 1, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p2"), 2, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d1"), 3, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p3"), 4, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d2"), 5, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d3"), 6, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d4"), 7, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p4"), 8, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d5"), 9, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d6"), 10, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d7"), 11, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d8"), 12, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d9"), 13, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d10"), 14, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d11"), 15, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p5"), 16, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("d12"), 17, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("Prueba de paridad"), 18, 0);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("Bit de paridad"), 19, 0);

                    hamT2.add(new Text("Palabra de datos recibida:"), 0, 1);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p1"), 0, 2);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p2"), 0, 3);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p3"), 0, 4);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p4"), 0, 5);
                    hamT2.add(new Text("p5"), 0, 6);

                    hamT2.setHgap(30);
                    hamT2.setVgap(45);

                    for(int i = 0; i < matrix2.size(); i++) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < matrix2.get(i).size(); j++) {
                            hamT2.add(new Text(matrix2.get(i).get(j)), j+1, i+1);
                        }
                    }

                    String state;
                    if(solution.bitDetected == 0) {
                        state = "No se encontraron errores";
                    }else {
                        state = "Se detectó un error en el bit número: " + solution.bitDetected;
                    }
                    detection = new Text(state);
                    detection.setFont(new Font(15));

                    secondT = new HBox(10);
                    secondT.getChildren().addAll(hamT2);

                    canvasHam3.getChildren().addAll(secondT, detection, restart);

                    bitToChange.setText("");

                    try {
                        fadeTransition(canvasBit, canvasHam3, ham3);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
                VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);
                dialogVbox.getChildren().add(new Text("Su entrada no es valida" + "\nIngrese otra entrada"));
                dialogVbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
                Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 300, 70);
                dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
                dialog.show();
                bitToChange.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    //Default is mainScene
    window.setTitle("Código Hamming - codificador y simulador de errores - Diseño Lógico Grupo 1");
    window.setScene(mainScene);
    window.centerOnScreen();
    window.show();
}

public String reverseBit(String bit) {
    if(bit.equals("1")) {
        return "0";
    }else {
        return "1";
    }
}

public void fadeTransition(VBox from, VBox to, Scene load) throws InterruptedException {
    FadeTransition t2 = new FadeTransition();
    t2.setDuration(Duration.millis(400));
    t2.setNode(to);
    t2.setFromValue(0);
    t2.setToValue(1);

    FadeTransition t = new FadeTransition();
    t.setDuration(Duration.millis(400));
    t.setNode(from);
    t.setFromValue(1);
    t.setToValue(0);
    t.play();
    t.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            window.setScene(load);
            t2.play();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Hope someone can help me,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your jar is unable to find **javafx.application.Application**.

Assuming that you have tried to run your jar as follows,

```
java -jar your_jar.jar
```

then the library must be in a directory below the current one

```
lib\
```

Check whether the relevant jar for javafx.application.Application under lib\  directory